# How to fix my RSpec syntax for version 2.99?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

I recently upgraded my Rails 4 application from RSpec 2.X to 2.99 and despite having run [Transpec](https://github.com/yujinakayama/transpec) already, some of my tests are still failing.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Invoice, :type => :model do

  before :each do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @invoice = FactoryGirl.create(:invoice, :user => @user)
  end

  it "is not open" do
    expect {
      FactoryGirl.create(:payment, :invoice => @invoice, :amount => 100)  
    }.to change{@invoice.reload.open?}.from(true).to(false)
  end

  it "is open" do
    expect {
      FactoryGirl.create(:payment, :invoice => @invoice, :amount => 99.99)  
    }.to_not change{@invoice.reload.open?}.to(false)
  end

end
```

The first test passes just like before the RSpec upgrade.

The second test, however, throws an error:

```
Failure/Error: expect {
   `expect { }.not_to change { }.to()` is deprecated.
```

What must I change my syntax to?

I've already tried a couple of things like `not_to`, `be_falsey` etc. Nothing worked so far.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't assert that the value doesn't change to something, just assert that it doesn't change:

```
it "is open" do
  expect {
    FactoryGirl.create(:payment, :invoice => @invoice, :amount => 99.99)  
  }.to_not change { @invoice.reload.open? }
end
```

That doesn't test the initial value of `@invoice.reload.open?`, but you should have a separate test for that anyway. You don't need to test it again in this test.

Nonetheless, in RSpec 3 you can use `.from` by itself to test that the value that doesn't change has a given initial value:

```
it "is open" do
  expect {
    FactoryGirl.create(:payment, :invoice => @invoice, :amount => 99.99)  
  }.to_not change { @invoice.reload.open? }.from(false)
end
```

You can't do that yet in RSpec 2; `.to_not change {}.from` passes if the value passed to `.from` is not what is expected. In RSpec 2.99 that causes a warning.

Comment: That works. Thank you! I will upgrade to RSpec 3 shortly and then also adjust my syntax.